# How do I update Flash 10.2 hardware mouse cursor immediately, before mouse move?

Tags: flash, mouse-cursor

As of Flash 10.2, Flash supports hardware accelerated mouse cursors:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/native-mouse-cursors.html

Yay!

Unfortunately, the mouse cursor doesn't update until AFTER the mouse moves. You can see this behavior on the web page above. If you click "Set to custom cursor" in the sample app at the bottom of the article, you'll see that the cursor doesn't change until you move the mouse.

Anyone have a trick for updating the mouse cursor immediately, before the user moves the mouse? I tried doing Mouse.hide(); Mouse.show(); but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Google Chrome? This is a known issue in Chrome.

I can't find it in the Chrome bugbase, but now I notice it is mentioned in the comments of the article that you linked to above.